# Modeling global and private parameters

Tags: sql-server, database-design, ssis

I'm trying to model a database that will be used for management and execution of SSIS packages. The entities are Client, Job and Package. A Job is the managed unit that references Client and Package.

I need to model parameters for the Package. Some parameters are Global, common to all clients. Others pertain to a particular client. The source server, is a good example of a client parameter and target server is global to all clients. Here's the model I have so far:

[image: Parameters]

Here is a scenario:

Global Parameters:

- SSIS_ServerName
- StagingServerName
- StagingUserName
- StagingPassword
- LogServerName
- LogUserName
- LogPassword

Client Parameters:

- SourceServerName
- SourceUserName
- SourcePassword
- SourceDatabase
- StagingDatabase
- BlockSize
- AllotedRunTime

It doesn't seem very clean to me. Anyone have a suggestion how to better model the parameters?

It's the relationship of PackageParameter to ClientParameter and GlobalParameter I don't quite know what to do with. PackageParameter lists the names of all parameters for the package and whether they are client or global. The values for those parameters would come from either the ClientParameter or the GlobalParameter, depending on the type.

Comment: Can't you just add joibId to the GlobalParams and ClientParams tables?

Comment: You have a typo in PackageParameters - `ParameteScope` Why do you abbreviate Params for global but spell it out on the Client/Package tables? I assume it's intentional that you singular Job/Client/Package and pluralize the Params/Parameters tables?  Could you provide some examples of your various parameter data? The examples I'm thinking of don't smell right

Comment: Hi there, @billinkc, The diagram is something I threw together for an illustration here, I didn't want to post the distracting stuff. Thanks for catching the typo.

Comment: @JamesAnderson, that won't really work because global parameters apply to all jobs and client parameters would apply to all jobs for the client.

Comment: Added a parameter example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to do away with GlobalParameter and use a special PackageID (0) for global parameters. Simplifies matters a great deal in both the model and the code.